# Is it safe to remove/modify default WordPress classes/templates to implement BEM?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, bem

I am creating a WordPress theme using BEM methodology for public release. To implement BEM methodology, I am removing/modifying some default WordPress templates and classes. For example, to implement BEM methodology in post comment list, I have created custom walker class:

```
<?php
// Walker class used to create an HTML list of comments.
class BEM_Walker_Comment extends Walker_Comment {

    // Starts the list before the elements are added.
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth + 1;
        $output .= '<ol class="comment__children">' . "\n";
    }

    // Ends the list of items after the elements are added.
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth + 1;
        $output .= "</ol>\n";
    }

    // Starts the element output.
    public function start_el( &$output, $comment, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $depth++;
        $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $depth;
        $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

        if ( ! empty( $args['callback'] ) ) {
            ob_start();
            call_user_func( $args['callback'], $comment, $args, $depth );
            $output .= ob_get_clean();
            return;
        }

        if ( ( 'pingback' === $comment->comment_type || 'trackback' === $comment->comment_type ) && $args['short_ping'] ) {
            ob_start();
            $this->ping( $comment, $depth, $args );
            $output .= ob_get_clean();
        } else {
            ob_start();
            $this->html5_comment( $comment, $depth, $args );
            $output .= ob_get_clean();
        }
    }

    // Ends the element output, if needed.
    public function end_el( &$output, $comment, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( ! empty( $args['end-callback'] ) ) {
            ob_start();
            call_user_func( $args['end-callback'], $comment, $args, $depth );
            $output .= ob_get_clean();
            return;
        }
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

    // Outputs a comment in the HTML5 format.
    protected function html5_comment( $comment, $depth, $args ) {
        ?>
        <li <?php $this->comment_class( $this->has_children ? 'comment__parent' : '', $comment ); ?>>
            <article class="comment__body">
                <footer class="comment__meta">
                    <div class="comment__author">
                        <?php
                        if ( 0 !== $args['avatar_size'] ) {
                            echo get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'] );
                        }

                        $url     = get_comment_author_url( $comment );
                        $author  = get_comment_author( $comment );
                        if ( empty( $url ) || 'http://' === $url ) {
                            $author_name = $author;
                        } else {
                            $author_name = '<a class="comment__author-url" href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" rel="external nofollow">' . esc_html( $author ) . '</a>';
                        }
                        printf( '<b class="comment__author-name">%s</b>', $author_name );
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-metadata">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment, $args ) ); ?>">
                            <time datetime="<?php comment_time( 'c' ); ?>">
                                <?php printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'runway' ), get_comment_date( '', $comment ), get_comment_time() ); ?>
                            </time>
                        </a>
                        <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'runway' ), '<span class="comment__edit">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ( '0' === $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
                    <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'runway' ); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </footer>
                <div class="comment__content">
                    <?php comment_text(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array(
                    'add_below' => 'div-comment',
                    'depth'     => $depth,
                    'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
                    'before'    => '<div class="comment__reply">',
                    'after'     => '</div>',
                ) ) );
                ?>
            </article>
        <?php
    }

    // Generates semantic classes for each comment element.
    protected function comment_class( $class = '', $comment = null, $post_id = null, $echo = true ) {
        $classes = join( ' ', get_comment_class( $class, $comment, $post_id ) );

        $classes = str_replace( ' byuser',          ' comment--by-user',        $classes );
        $classes = str_replace( ' comment-author-',' comment--author-',     $classes );
        $classes = str_replace( ' bypostauthor',    ' comment--by-post-author', $classes );
        $classes = str_replace( ' odd',         ' comment--odd',            $classes );
        $classes = str_replace( ' alt',         ' comment--alt',            $classes );
        $classes = str_replace( ' even',            ' comment--even',           $classes );
        $classes = str_replace( ' thread-odd',      ' comment--thread-odd',     $classes );
        $classes = str_replace( ' thread-alt',      ' comment--thread-alt',     $classes );
        $classes = str_replace( ' thread-even', ' comment--thread-even',    $classes );
        $classes = str_replace( ' depth-',          ' comment--depth-',         $classes );

        // Separates classes with a single space, collates classes for comment DIV.
        $class = 'class="' . $classes . '"';
        if ( $echo ) {
            echo $class;
        } else {
            return $class;
        }
    }
} // BEM_Walker_Comment class
?>
```

Similarly, I have also created walker class for Navigation menu, and modified comment form to implement BEM methodology.

**But is it safe to remove/modify default WordPress classes and templates?**

Answer (score 1):

> **But is it safe to remove/modify default WordPress classes and templates?**

Yes!

I use BEM for my WordPress templates and I remove all the original CSS classes from WordPress. The only things we need to keep are:

1. `id="s"` for the search field;
2. Several elements in the comments, including the `id="com-{commentId}"` on comment items, it is used by a JS helper from WordPress to move the "reply" field.

Comment: @BHUSHAN I don't use many plugins. The plugins I use are no problem. In general, to insert content somewhere, WordPress plugins use WordPress filters.

Comment: To clarify... it safe to remove/modify default WordPress classes and templates *in your own theme* - not directly in the WP code or base theme (if you are using a child theme). Just thought I'd add that in case another user didn't notice that the OP is using their own theme and thought it was safe to change the WP files directly :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Good point. And I edited. I've just remember there is a small JS script from the WP core that needs some IDs and/or classes to work. I'll search a more exhaustive list this evening.